# Php for each loop prints out "print(2)"

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, printing, echo

I have a loop in which I am iterating over an array and its working correctly, however, it prints out too much stuff : print(2) "81" 81 . In my case I want it to print out only 81 as a value.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['devices']) && is_array($_POST['devices'])) {

        foreach ($_POST['devices'] as $deviceId) {
            var_dump($deviceId);
            echo "$deviceId";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove var_dump. This is just a typographical mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing the var_dump($deviceId);

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

if (isset($_POST['devices']) && is_array($_POST['devices'])) {

    foreach ($_POST['devices'] as $deviceId) {

        echo "$deviceId";
    }
}
}
```